# What is って in どうかしらって?

Tags: meaning

Which meaning of って is used in this case and what is its purpose?

> 「そうねぇ、私も考えていたのよ。捨ててしまうんなら取っておいたらどうかしら**って**。」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「そうねぇ、私{わたし}も考{かんが}えていたのよ。捨{す}ててしまうんなら取{と}っておいたらどうかしら**って**。」

≒

> 「そうねぇ。捨ててしまうんなら取っておいたらどうかしら**って**、私も考えていたのよ。」

≒

> 「そうねぇ。『捨ててしまうんなら取っておいたらどうかしら』**って**、私も考えていたのよ。」

The 「って」 is clearly the quotative particle.

**「～～って/と考える」** is the bare form.

> "Yeah, right.  I , too, was thinking that it would (probably) be just as good to keep it as to throw it away."