# Meaning of ってえ in「「いじめ」がどうしたってぇ」

Tags: manga, particle-って

From Yugioh chapter 1,

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

> お前ら「いじめ」がどうしたってぇ

I think it means something like "What did you say about bully?" I am not sure about the どうしたってぇ part, especially ってぇ.

Comment: oh wow is this ygo s0? or ygo duel monsters?

Comment: @BCLC I think it's S0 on the first part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the って is the same as っていう as a colloquial version of という.

Just like [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54774/45489), どうしたって is a version of どうしたというのか. So the sentence is literally like *Hey you, what about "bullying"?*

The last ぇ simply expresses that て is pronounced with prolonged vowel.